# Request method 'POST' not supported - Strange Occurance

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, post, spring-boot

In our project we have a Controller class annotated with @RestController implementing a Interface annotated with @RestMapping and the methods defined in the interfaces are annotated with @RestMapping.

**Issue:** When i hit my POST method that has either a @RequestHeader or @RequestBody parameter, i get "Request method 'POST' not supported" with 405 status code and when i hit my GET method that has @RequestHeader i get "No Message Available" with 404 status code. I enabled debugging by giving

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

I am able to see the SOP's that i had put in the methods. So its calling my method and executing the statements and not returning the value.

But, when i stop using the interface and use only my controller class and define all the annotations in my Controller class, its working perfectly, regardless of giving @RequestHeader or @RequestBody in my method parameters.

I just want to know why the POST call or GET call is not working when i use an Interface to define the method parameters that includes @RequestHeader or @RequestBody

Below is my code snippet:

```
//My Controller Class
@RestController
public class MyController implements MyInterface{
@Override
public WSResponse getPFDData(@RequestHeader(name= HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)  String bearerToken) throws Exception {
   System.out.println("This is Printing despite of Request method 'POST' not supported error");
}

//My Interface Class
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/v1/myapi")
public interface PFDService {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,  value="/",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     WSResponse getPFDData(@RequestHeader(name= HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String bearerToken) throws Exception;
}
```

Below is the exact error message i am getting in the response.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1464210265555,
  "status": 405,
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
  "path": "/v1/myapi/"
}
```

And for GET method i am getting below response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1464210501465,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/v1/myapi/"
}
```

Please let me know if you need additional information from my debug log.

Comment: Message saying there is no method annotated with POST, isn't it? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As @Nambari mentioned, you have not created a method that has RequestMethod.POST set. That is why the response says "Method Not Allowed".

For the GET request:
your question has the path "/v1/myapi" however your comment has the path as "/v1/pfd/". Make sure you are using the correct path.

Comment: My bad, i had updated the question now. I do have ReuqestMethod.POST in my code and i still get the 405 error. Regarding the GET, thats again a typo in my comment. I am using /v1/myapi only in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
 //Get method
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,  value="/getPFDData",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
         WSResponse getPFDData(@RequestHeader(name= HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String bearerToken) throws Exception;
    }
     //POST method
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,  value="/postData"){
        //do your stuff here
    }
```

and you access them by the url:

```
GET:  /v1/myapi/getPFDData
POST: /v1/myapi/postData
```

Comment: I just updated my question. I am having only one POST method and its still not working.